# C# - Close input stream of child process

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, inputstream

My C# program needs to send data to a 3rd-party program via its standard input. However, the program waits for the input stream to reach EOF before processing. Here my code:

```
// Starts the process.
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "foo.exe";
process.Start();

// Sends data to child process.
var input = process.StandardInput;
input.WriteLine("eval('2 * PI')");
input.Flush();
input.Close();

// Reads the result.
var output = process.StandardOutput;
var result = output.ReadLine();
```

The child program won't do anything and my C# code becomes stuck at `output.ReadLine()` call. However if I kill the C# process, then the child starts to work exactly on the data I've sent. How can I make the child encounter an EOF while I'm still alive?

Answer (score 2):

StreamWriter might not be sending an actual eof when it closes the stream.  You could try writing your own to the stream just before you close it.  Something like this might work:

```
input.Write((char)26);
```

You may have to find out what the process expects for eof.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. The process expects an actual end of file, not an inline EOF character.

Comment: If closing the stream doesn't signify end of file what does it expect?  Maybe redirecting the input back to the program wil give the program the signal it needs.

Comment: This worked for me.  I never realized that Windows used SUB (0x1A) for EOF, rather than using EOT (0x04) like unix.